# Does Google Cloud Speech API support regional endpoints

Tags: google-speech-api

Is it possible to co-locate the cloud speech service in a region where the calling application resides or is there just a single endpoint?

I am wanting to reduce latency by getting my client application as close to the google service as possible, my client application is running in Azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First it's important to clarify that google speech api has 2 ways of uploading files:
 1. from your local drive directly to the API
 2. from your google cloud storage (gcs) to the speech api

With this in mind, google cloud storage can be defined as multi-regional or regional to reduce the latency of any request against the storaget itself or the speech api from the storage.

I hope this helps